# excecute a python script with argument in another python script

Tags: python, regex, loops, exec, command-line-arguments

I have a python script that should be called with two argument:

```
$ python ./script.py arg1 arg2
```

The content of this script is sth like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import commands

if len(sys.argv) != 3:
       print 'Usage: python %s <IP1> <IP2>' % (sys.argv[0])
       sys.exit()
.
.
.
with open('/tmp/file.txt', 'r+') as f:
        for line in f:
                execfile("script.py --host $line")
```

But this is not correct, when I use this type of `execfile` this is wrong because:

it says the syntax is not correct..The correct form is execfile("script.py") but I have one argument and also I have variable line from my for loop

I want to run `script.py` with `--host` and variable that should be for each line from `file.txt`

How can I do that?

Thank you

Comment: Because it says the syntax is not correct..The correct form is `execfile("script.py")` but I have one argument and also I have variable `line` from my `for loop`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`execfile` run a python script by loading it, not as a script. You should use `os.system` or `subprocess.Popen` for that.

for instance:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import commands
import os # Change here!!

if len(sys.argv) != 3:
       print 'Usage: python %s <IP1> <IP2>' % (sys.argv[0])
       sys.exit()
.
.
.
with open('/tmp/file.txt', 'r+') as f:
        for line in f:
                os.system("script.py --host %s" % line)
```

run the command with [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html?highlight=subprocess#subprocess) will allows you store the standar and error ouput from the command.

Using `subprocess`:

```
import subprocess

with open('/tmp/file.txt', 'r+') as f:
        for line in f:
            proc = subprocess.Popen(["script.py", "--host", line], sdtout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
            out, err = proc.communicate()  # out: stadar output, err: error output
```

Comment: Can you tell me how? in more detailed answer in my case?(I mean argument with variable line) thanks

Comment: use the `%` syntax for doing that for instance: `os.system("script.py --host %s" % line)`. Answer have been updated to reflect this change.

Comment: pardon, can we redirect the output of it to a file?

Comment: yes, ofcourse you can `os.system("script.py --host %s >> other.txt" % line)`

Comment: Ok, you should post another question about that. Be fair, this question is already answered.